# Regular Expression Difficulty

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, regular-expression

I'm trying to extract `456` from the string `:123:456:` as follows:

```
select regexp_substr(':123:456:', ':(\d+):', 1, 2, 'i', 1) from dual
```

However, this query returns `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works fine:

```
select regexp_substr(':123:456:', '(\d+):', 1, 2, 'i', 1) from dual;
```

I think yours fails because the opening and closing colons won't get matched by both occurrences (because the first match is greedy).

Answer (score -2):

```
select regexp_substr(':123:456:','[^:]+',2,2) from dual
```

Comment: If this is substantially different from the accepted answer posted by Phil 10 months ago, please add some context explaining why.

Comment: This will match on `:123:abc:` which doesn't sound desirable, but fail to match on `::456:` which might be.